# Is there any way to track how much rent was paid given by an account address and timestamp in solana?

Tags: solana

I'm new to solana. Currently, I'm working on an app that supports user to track their wallet historical balance and transactions.

For example, given by an account and time period range, the app will calculate the opening and closing balance and how much sol were sent and recevied during the time range.Since the rpc dose not support such features, I fetch all the historical transactions of an account and instead of using prebalance and postbalance directly returned by rpc, I try to calculate the historical balance by every transcations.(I use the absolute value of the subtraction of the prebalance and postbalance to get the transfer amount in every transaction, so that I can get the sent and the received value.) I found that in solana the rent does not show in the transaction, which will cause the balance calculation error.

I'd like to know if there is any way to track how much rent was paid given by an account address and timestamp in solana? I tried googling it and didn't find a solution.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the rent-exempt balances are included in transactions.  For example, here's a transaction creating a USDC account: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/32oAkYzp47zF7DiPRFwMKLcknt6rhu43JW2yAfkEc2KgZpX35BoVeDBUs4kkiLWJ4wqoEFspndvGdUcB215jY931?cluster=testnet

There, you'll see that the new token account `2XBTsdaRTYdmsqLXRjjXonbVHCwvvGfHjBRfTXPcgnsS` received 0.00203928 SOL, and the funding account `4SnSuUtJGKvk2GYpBwmEsWG53zTurVM8yXGsoiZQyMJn` lost 0.00204428 SOL, which is higher since it paid for the transaction.

Roughly speaking, if you go though all a wallet's transactions, you can see if a payment was for rent-exemption if the destination account had 0 SOL to start, and the wallet paid for it.  Note that this isn't perfect, since a lot of balances can move in a transaction!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I think what I want to do is to capture how much rent the account paid so that I can use the value to calculate the balance instead of using balance returend by api.  I understand that rent-exempt balances are included in transactions, but seems like the collected rent is unknown in transactions from rpc.

Comment: Correct, collected rent is unknown, since rent collection happens in two ways.  The first is eager rent, paid if a rent-paying account is referenced in a transaction, collected once per epoch.  The second is lazy rent, which is collected at some point over the course of an epoch, even if the account is never touched.  You can figure out eager rent collection based on any "disappearing" lamports in a transaction.  And lazy rent collection is kind of impossible.

Comment: Thankfully, none of this really matters anymore since rent-paying accounts have been disabled on mainnet for some time.

Comment: From my understanding,  the rent amount depends on the data size of per account. This behavior will happen in every epoch once, so those non-exempt accounts at least need to pay rent once in every epcoh and pay more rent everytime they are referenced in transactions.  You mentioned lazy and eager rent, so, the rent happening in each epoch is lazy rent and referenced in transactions is eager rent?  I found that using solana cli you can get rent per epoch by knowing the data size of an account, then does the rent amount are the same comparing rent per epoch and rent in every transactions?

Comment: Also, could you provide some articles or links about lazy and eager rent and rent-paying being disabled, so that I can have a further understanding? 
You said tracking lazy amount is kind ofr impossible.
I did find some adjacent transactions, for example,  sort by time, tx A -> txB -> ....
A post balance is unequal to B prebalance, which should be equal in normal, so i guess the gap of balance amount is the lazy rent? By comparing pre and post balance of transactions, is it possible to track all the collected rent? Anyway, again thanks for your answer